# python comparison in list with both numerical and categorical values

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I'm trying to compare some values in a list and it could be either numerical value or categorical value. Here's my code:

```
        if type(row[feature]) == int or type(row[feature] == float):
            if row[feature] <= this[feature][0]:
                this = this[feature][1]
                print("less than")
            else:
                this = this[feature][2]
                print("greater than")
        else:
            if row[feature] == this[feature][0]:
                print("same string")
                this = this[feature][1]
            else:
                print("diff string")
                this = this[feature][2]
```

If row[feature] has a numerical value, I want to do the greater than or less than comparison. And if it is a string, I want to do the equal to or not comparison.

For example, if row[feature] = 0 and this[feature][0] = 1, it should print "less than". And if row[feature] = 'f' and this[feature][0] = 't', it should print "diff string". Currently my code will still prints "less than" in this case. Did I do something wrong in the first if statement? Or how can I make it print "diff string"?

Comment: ``type(row[feature] == float)`` should be ``type(row[feature]) == float``, otherwise the result is ``bool`` and the whole if statement will always evaluate to ``True``.

Comment: Voting to close, because: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Comment: `isinstance` is the preferred way in python over `type`